# What does this key looking symbol (with 4 bars) indicate?

Tags: symbol

Im currently studying for my NEN3140 exam and I stumbeld acros this image:

[image: Screenshot electronic]

I have been poking around in google (and all the symbol questions I could find here) and the closest I got is this (page2):

https://www.reconelectrical.co.uk/image/data/pdfs/Electrical%20Symbols%20Guide.pdf

which makes me this it is a "Switch, general symbol double pole", after googleing som more I can find the top right symbol back as a double pole switch

But I can't find the "key/switch" **with 4 bars/poles?** back. Is it safe to think this is a 4 pole switch or is it somthing else?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me that it is a 4-pole (3-phase + ground) switch, because it is preceded by a triple fuse.

Comment: The one with two bars comes out of the IEC 60617 it seems, but I can't find the one you are looking for, but I don't have the original document available, so it might be in there.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen You mean 3-phase + neutral, you would never switch a ground wire!

Comment: Sorry, I am an low-current/voltage guy, for me ground, mass, neutral are all the same, but I know they are different in high-power stuff. But I can't edit a comment....

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen so I can safely assume this is a 4- pole (3-phase + neutral) switch? I can't find a symbol for it online (maybe the designer of this circuit made one up)?

Comment: Safely? As in betting your life on an educated guess from an non-power-electronics guy?? No way. But I'd call it a reasonable guess.

Comment: I used those when doing NEN 1010 in the Netherlands a loooong time ago. I found a Dutch reference: http://konect.goethals-jacobs.be/?page_id=96

Comment: @oldfart you mean the "dubbelpolig wissel" symbol? And in using them can you confirm wouters "reasonable" geuss :), that they are indeed 4-pole(3-phase+neutral switches)?

Comment: You find a single pole (Enkelpolige Schakelaar) and double pole (Dubblepolige) switch there. Those are the only ones I learned about. (As bachelor electronics you don't do much house wiring.) Extrapolation would give us Wouter's four pole switch. Note that it only mentions the number of "switches". How you connect them is not specified.